# check last command

Tags: bash

I want to execute some code every time `cd` is executed.  I'm getting hung up on actually testing if `cd` was the last command but I think I'm on the right track.  Here is what I've added to my bash_profile

```
update_prompt()
{
   if [ 'cd' = $1 ]; then
     #DO STUFF
   fi
}

PROMPT_COMMAND="update_prompt "$(!:0)"; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

This is close but it tries to actually execute the command in $1 rather than treat it as a string.  Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/175802) to a similar question on SuperUser may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a shell function that wraps `cd`, rather than using `PROMPT_COMMAND` to check the last command executed:

```
cd () {
    builtin cd "$@"
    # CUSTOM CODE HERE
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** this is the solution I came up with. It's not based on the question directly, but rather on @schwiz's explanations in the comments:

```
update_prompt()
{
        LAST=$(history | tail -n 1 | cut -d \  -f 5)
        if [ "cd" = "$LAST" ]; then
          # DO STUFF
        fi
}

PROMPT_COMMAND="update_prompt"
```

---

**Answering original question**: when comparing string variable put it in parentheses to avoid interpreting:

```
update_prompt()
{
  if [ 'cd' = "$1" ]; then
    # ...
  fi
}
```

Optionally you can consider defining an alias for `cd`:

```
alias cd='echo executed && cd'
```

Comment: Or use `[[ cd = $1 ]]` instead.

Comment: I dont think this would work, needs to be executed after cd not before. So its executed in the directory I cd into.

Comment: I understand. Anyway, just put the parentheses and it should work.

Comment: Still not working, now its like an empty string.  I threw a `echo "$1"` above my if statement to see why it wasn't working and it just prints an empty line.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more verbose way of writing `!:0` that seems to play better with `PROMPT_COMMAND`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='update_prompt $(history -p !:0); $PROMPT_COMMAND'.
```

The single quotes prevent the command substitution from happening until `PROMPT_COMMAND` is actually called. Technically, there is no history expansion happening; you are using the `history` command to process the `!:0` string as an argument, which does however have the same effect as the intended history expansion.

Comment: this is just treating my argument as the string "!:0" now

Comment: The above update still doesn't seem to work quite right. I might delete permanently.

Comment: The problem is that `!:0` is the command previous to the one just executed. It seems as if the history list isn't updated until after `PROMPT_COMMAND` is executed.

Comment: Well we are on the right track, I put the $(history -p !:0) line inside of my update_prompt function rather than in the PROMPT_COMMAND. However, it is still one behind.  I guess what I need is the current command not the previous one

Comment: I tried `!#:0`, but that only seems to work while actually typing a command.

Comment: See my other answer, which addresses the ultimate goal: executing some code following every use of `cd`.